# Delta table : COPY INTO only specific partitioned folders from S3 bucket

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I have one landing S3 buckets, which will receive each day some data, partitioned by date :

```
s3:/my_bucket/date=2020-01-01/my_data.txt
s3:/my_bucket/date=2020-01-02/my_data.txt
s3:/my_bucket/date=2020-01-03/my_data.txt
```

I did create a first test Delta table partitioned on date column, using SQL, then I did :

```
COPY INTO delta.my_table FROM (SELECT date, value FROM 's3:/my_bucket/') FILEFORMAT = TEXT
```

**Everything is working well**, then ...
Today I had a new partitionFolder on that bucket :

```
s3:/my_bucket/date=2020-01-04/my_data.txt
```

I have **NO idea** how to "copy into" only that new folders, and keep date partitioning value.
Basically, I can't re-use same sql statement to copy, because it will copy previous files (other date, which are already inside delta table).

I did try by specify directly folder path like that :

```
COPY INTO delta.my_table FROM (SELECT date, value FROM 's3:/my_bucket/date=2020-01-04') FILEFORMAT = TEXT
```

but Delta/Spark is not able to get "date column", because it's read directly files and not subfolder which contains date column information.

```
SQL AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'date' given input columns: [value];
```

I wanted to add some "Pattern" matching on subfolder like

```
    COPY INTO delta.my_table FROM (SELECT date, value FROM 's3:/my_bucket/') FILEFORMAT = TEXT 
PÄTTERN = 'date=2020-01-04/*'
```

but same errors, **spark is not able to understand that this folder is a new partition**.

My question is quite simple, is it possible to use **'COPY INTO'** from a **incremental partitioned s3 buckets** (like my example).

**PS** : My Delta table is an external table, which link to an other s3 bucket.
`s3:/my_bucket/` is supposed to be only landing zone and should be immutable.

Comment: As per their documentation, it says previously loaded files are skipped. Why do you think its copying the previous day files too?

"Loads data from a file location into a Delta table. This is a re-triable and idempotent operation—files in the source location that have already been loaded are skipped."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COPY INTO is idempotent operation - it won't load the data from the files that were already processed, at least until you explicitly will ask it with `COPY_OPTIONS(force=true)` (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/delta-copy-into.html)).

You can easily prove that with small experiment - I'm using DBFS just as an example:

- Load file with content `1` into file `dbfs:/tmp/cp-test/date=2022-05-16/1.txt` and import it:

[image]

- Check that you have data loaded:

[image]

- Create a file with content `2`, upload it to the file `dbfs:/tmp/cp-test/date=2022-05-17/1.txt`, and import it as well - you see that we imported only one row, although we have old files there:

[image]

- And if we look into data, we see that we have only 2 rows as it's supposed:

[image]